# Retrieve "Remaining Quota" for Youtube API V3 programmatically

Tags: android, google-api-console, youtube-data-api

The Youtube API implements a quota system to limit the number of api calls. The remaining Quota can be viewed via the Google API Console.

I like to retrieve the remaining quota programmatically for display in Android.

How do I go about doing this?